# Adding Environment Variable in Windows 7

Tags: cmake, environment-variables, gsl

I am trying to use CMake and I need to add an environment variable GSL_ROOT_DIR in windows 7, so that %GSL_ROOT_DIR%\include contains the GSL header files and %GSL_ROOT_DIR%\lib contains the GSL libraries.
Could you tell me exactly how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Press the start button.  (alternatively: windows key + r, then sysdm.cpl)
- right click "Computer" then click properties.
- Click advanced system settings.
- Click Environment variables.
- Add the variable you need + the correct path.

**EDIT:**

point %GSL_ROOT_DIR% to the base directory of where you extracted the GSL library. I.e. if you downloaded the developer files from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsl.htm) and extracted it to c:\libs\gsl\ then your %GSL_ROOT_DIR% should be "C:\libs\gsl" (if you look at the zip file, it contains both an include, and a lib folder).

Comment: How can I add 2 values to a same variable ? such that, %GSL_ROOT_DIR%\include contains the GSL header files and %GSL_ROOT_DIR%\lib contains the GSL libraries.